How to Hide Real IP of Local Network Using Squid Proxy and External Proxy Server
I'm looking to enhance the security and privacy of my local network by hiding its real IP addresses. The way I've gone about it is the following: a local gateway for all client machines that runs squid and forwards traffic to a remote proxy server.
This is what squid.conf file looks like:
http_port 3128 transparent
http_port 3129
acl localnet src 192.168.1.0/24
http_access allow localnet
http_access deny all

# Define the parent proxy
cache_peer XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX parent 35298 0 no-query no-digest default
never_direct allow all


via off
forwarded_for truncate
follow_x_forwarded_for deny all
request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
header_access X_Forwarded_For deny all

request_header_access From deny all
request_header_access Server deny all
request_header_access WWW-Authenticate deny all
request_header_access Link deny all
request_header_access Cache-Control deny all
request_header_access Proxy-Connection deny all
request_header_access X-Cache deny all
request_header_access X-Cache-Lookup deny all
request_header_access Via deny all
request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
request_header_access Pragma deny all
request_header_access Keep-Alive deny all

My iptables look as such:
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s8 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i enp0s8 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3128
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE

I've tried a lot of different combinations of settings for the file but I always get the same two issues:

Whatismyip.com can see my real IP address and not the remote proxy's
I get SSL errors on some websites.

Is this even the right approach? What would be the best approach?
Thank you

443 will not work for redirection; 80 can be manipulated anyway, but 443 usually has a direct connection and will fail if changed.
